# access arrays of arrays or objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to have an array of arrays like the following function shows.

```
function getarrayinfo(index)
{
    var myarray1=new Array();
    myarray[0]=[1,1.1,1.2];
    myarray[1]=[0.1,0.2,0.3];
    var myarray2=new Array();

    for (myarray2[i])
    {
        myarray2[i]=myarray[i];
        i++;
    }
```

so I can do something like...

```
{
    var arrayinfo=myarray2[marray1[index]];
    return arrayinfo;
}
```

but this type of code does not seem to run..

Comment: Seriously? That `for`...

Comment: It's not clear what you need. To create an array of arrays in Javascript you just need to define each element as an array. Ex: `var arrayOfArrays = new Array(new Array('1','2'),new Array('3','4'));` then `arrayOfArrays[0][0]` would be `1`

Comment: @koala_dev Or the much simpler array literal syntax: `var arrayOfArrays = [['1', '2'], ['3', '4']];`

Comment: Javascript doesn't have multidimensional arrays, merely jagged / nested arrays. There's no special syntax for this, you'll have to explicitly return an array of arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Why will it run where there are **Syntax errors** in your code...

```
 for (myarray2[i])
```

This is not how a for loop is written.  Also you seem to access the index with `i` which is never initialized.

ALso

```
var myarray1=new Array();
myarray[0]=[1,1.1,1.2];
```

Created an `myarray1` and trying to insert into `myarray`

Better to initialize an array with `[]` instead

Try this

```
for (var i=0; i< myarray1.length; i++) {
   myarray2[i]=myarray[i];
 }
```

**Code**

```
 var myarray1 = []; // Use this to create an array
 myarray1.push([1, 1.1, 1.2]); // Use push to instert instead of an index
 myarray1.push([0.1, 0.2, 0.3]);
 var myarray2 = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < myarray1.length; i++) {
     myarray2.push(myarray1[i]);
 }

 console.log(myarray2);
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ZCW4P/)**

Comment: Or `myarray1.forEach(myarray2.push, myarray2)` using array functions.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:Understand what is Multidimensional array (in your language--arrays of arrays)

```
var arr = [1, 2, [3, 4], 5];

alert (arr[2][1]); //alerts "4"
```

Step 2:this is what you want:

```
var container_array=[[a,b,c],[d,e,f]];
```

Step 3:Solution

```
var container_array=new Array();
    sub_array_1=[1,1.1,1.2];
    sub_array_2=[0.1,0.2,0.3];


 container_array.push([1, 1.1, 1.2]);
 container_array.push([0.1, 0.2, 0.3]);

console.log(container_array)
```

[Example-->push in javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)

If you have many subarrays,then go for the loops